# Spring MockMvc test : Swagger allowableValues not filtering bad argument

Tags: java, spring, rest, mockito, swagger

I have a Java API (Post) that requires a `PersonDTO` as request input.

There is a field `gender` in the `PersonDTO`, I annotated with `allowableValues = man, woman` and it's working well when I call API externally. If I put some other value, it will show 400 bad request code.

But when I'm doing my integration test, I use `MockMvc` to do a post `PersonDTO` with `gender` of some other value, and it returns 200 instead of 400 - that means `allowableValues = man, woman` is not working.

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger-annotation is used for swagger-ui only to provide a dropdown with possible values ([see example of swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta1eG.png)) so that is ignored by MockMvc. To check allowed values in your DTO use a Enum for field gender instead of String or use Bean-Validation @Pattern with regex for the field gender.

Comment: Hi, do you mean even if I call my API using a client (not Swagger UI) , the allowed values will not control the input ? So I have to add the control in my code ?

Comment: Hello. Yes, that's what i experienced using this Annotation.